# Choosing a data structure to store the words in a sentence and their starting position

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, sentence

I'm preparing for an interview and one of the questions that tends to come up is this:

Presented with a sentence (e.g, the song is the best song) broken down into words and the indices of the first letter of the word, i.e. "the" - 0, 12; "song" - 4,21; "is" - 9; "best" - 16; choose a data structure to store this information and, using that data structure, reconstruct the sentence.

My initial attempt involves storing the words in a hashmap where the key is the word and the value is an array of positions. This is totally doable but gets quite complicated with nested for loops and annoying problems at border indices, reading in spaces at appropriate locations etc.

I have the code done for it, so if anyone would like to look I'll post (it's long and makes for a riveting read!!)

Anyway, to my question: can anyone suggest a more efficient way of representing and reconstructing the data? I'd love to try another way but this is all I've come up with so far

Comment: This may not be a great question because it fails the 'is this a matter of opinion' test. But you might get some better results by rephrasing the question and/or posting pseudocode.

Comment: What if the words are repeated? Do you have to make a note of all the positions?

Comment: @noMAD: yes, in my example above "the" occurs at positions 0 and 12, "song" is at positions 4 and 21 etc. Using this info I have to reconstruct the sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one who interviews candidates of varying skill levels, I would want the interviewee to ask more questions before deciding on a final data structure.

- Will the data be used exclusively to reconstruct the sentence? If so, a list would be preferable.
- Do you need to be able to look up word positions? If so, your structure is fine.
- What other questions might you ask about the sentence using this data?

One option is to create a `WordPosition` object for each individual word that contains the word, its position, and a reference to the next word. These would form a linked list that makes reconstructing the sentence a trivial in-order traversal. Store these as you have in a map with the words as the keys and a list of `WordPosition`s for each word.

Comment: I guess I was just taking the information at face value (the info is coming from a person who completed the interview previously). Apparently the words and indices are presented in tabular format. I figured that they had to be kept in this format, i.e. word being the key, positions being the values. If we can change this about then it makes it a lot easier - can use the index as the key (they will be unique) or as you suggest - a linked list of words

Comment: The key is to ask questions as this demonstrates qualities interviewers look for in candidates. If the answer is "you must use a map" then use a map. If you don't ask, it shows you make assumptions based on limited data.

Comment: Posting on here has definitely opened my eyes to the fact that asking questions is key. Thanks for your advice...hopefully it will pay off

Answer (score 0):

How about let the keys be the positions?then you don't need to use arrays.and you can use a treemap, then the integrator will return the tokens in order.

Comment: I would definitely have approached it this way if I hadn't made the assumption that the word had to be linked specifically to a list of indices. In an interview situation, I would definitely ask for clarification on this point

Answer (score 0):

I'm avoiding using a map here, since that seems too simple.

```
class Sentence {
  String[] words;//Every word in the sentence
  int[][] word_positions;//{index into the word array,start position of that word in the sentence}

  String getSentence(){
    //Find the last position of the last character of the last word
    int length = word_positions[word_positions.length][1] 
                 + word[word_positions[word_positions.length][0]].length();
    //Allocate an appropriate sized array
    char[] sentence = new char[length];

    //Iterate through every word in the sentence, putting it into the correct place.
    for (int w=0; w<word_positions.length; w++){
      //figure out where in the array this word will start
      int start = word_positions[w][1];
      //get the word
      char[] word = words[wordpositions[w][0].toCharArray();
      //copy it into the master array at the correct position
      for (int letter=0; letter<word.length; letter++ ) {
        sentence[start+letter] = word[letter];
      }
    }

    return sentence.toString();
  }
}
```

Please comment if this doesn't cover part of the question. I'm not sure if I understand the whole scope of what's being asked.

Comment: First, what kind of a `for loop` is that? Second, what exactly is your code doing? How are you tokenizing the sentences to words and storing them?

Comment: @noMAD The question didn't include asking how the words were tokenizing, just some scheme to store and reconstruct the data. I'll comment the code more!

Comment: @Nathaniel: This is more or less how I've coded it myself although instead of using a 2D array, I've used a hashmap where the value is an array. Not sure what the impact that choice has on efficiency etc but we have the same approach in reconstructing the sentence.

Comment: @cash22 I don't think there is much efficiency loss by using a hash, though you do run into the problem of duplicated words. If this is your implementation already, what is your question?

Comment: Take another look at your for loop syntax.